# Excel VBA Assignment by value or by reference?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two objects of the same class which have a property that's an array of doubles (Double()), and I would like to do the following:

```
Obj1.arr_property = Obj2.arr_property
```

Is the above going to assign by value or by reference? If by reference, how to make it by value instead?

Comment: Why not do an experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that you assign with `Set` only copies the reference to the new variable, not the data.
You do not use `Set`, so all values of the array are copied, not just the reference to the array.

You actually cannot use `Set` in this case, even if you'd want to. `Set` is only allowed for objects. Arrays are no objects, so they can only be assigned the way you did.

Things are a bit different if you do not use the assignment operator `=`, but pass a value to a function. But that is another question.

Comment: just to make sure I understand correctly: If I don't use `Set`, the value is assigned, and not the reference. So, if I were to later modify `Obj1.arr_property`, it won't modify `Obj2.arr_property`, right?

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the values, not the reference, into `Obj1.arr_property`.

One important thing to keep in mind is that the destination array must be dynamic/re-sizable. This means it needs to be declared in this form,`Dim arr_property() As Double`, rather than something like `Dim arr_property(10) As Double`. Otherwise you will get a [Can't assign to array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264711.aspx) error.